# Nativescript Sidekick iOS build fails on windows

Tags: nativescript, sidekick

I have an NS Core 6.2 app which builds correctly for Android, but fails for iOS on my Windows 10 machine when using Sidekick.  The same app builds correctly on my mac machine.

Here is the error:

```html
[20-02-25 08:42:40.238] Build failed. Build failed. Reason is: 'Build failed with error code 2'. Additional information: [00:00:35.043] [WARN]  ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
[00:00:35.045] [WARN]   CompileC /tmp/builds/_/9207ad242e18a06d9987f7f799fb7f3cb720b864/6.2.2/6.2.0/tkmktmobileapp/platforms/ios/DerivedData/tkmktmobileapp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/tkmktmobileapp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/MBProgressHUD.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MBProgressHUD.o /tmp/builds/_/9207ad242e18a06d9987f7f799fb7f3cb720b864/6.2.2/6.2.0/tkmktmobileapp/platforms/ios/Pods/MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC /tmp/builds/_/9207ad242e18a06d9987f7f799fb7f3cb720b864/6.2.2/6.2.0/tkmktmobileapp/platforms/ios/DerivedData/tkmktmobileapp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/tkmktmobileapp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/MBProgressHUD.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MBProgressHUD.o /tmp/builds/_/9207ad242e18a06d9987f7f799fb7f3cb720b864/6.2.2/6.2.0/tkmktmobileapp/platforms/ios/Pods/MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)
[00:00:35.371] [ERROR] ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
CompileC /tmp/builds/_/9207ad242e18a06d9987f7f799fb7f3cb720b864/6.2.2/6.2.0/tkmktmobileapp/platforms/ios/DerivedData/tkmktmobileapp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/tkmktmobileapp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/MBProgressHUD.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MBProgressHUD.o /tmp/builds/_/9207ad242e18a06d9987f7f799fb7f3cb720b864/6.2.2/6.2.0/tkmktmobileapp/platforms/ios/Pods/MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC /tmp/builds/_/9207ad242e18a06d9987f7f799fb7f3cb720b864/6.2.2/6.2.0/tkmktmobileapp/platforms/ios/DerivedData/tkmktmobileapp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/tkmktmobileapp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/MBProgressHUD.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MBProgressHUD.o /tmp/builds/_/9207ad242e18a06d9987f7f799fb7f3cb720b864/6.2.2/6.2.0/tkmktmobileapp/platforms/ios/Pods/MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)
'Build failed with error code 2'.
```

I am not sure how to proceed from here.  Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: You can not build iOS apps on Windows, you may give a try for cloud builds though.

Comment: @Manoj: Yes you can, by using Sidekick.  I thought that this was evident.  I will update my question.  If I was trying to build it from the command line, my error would have been totally different.

Comment: Sidekick is just a tool, GUI for the command line. It's nothing special, you can never locally build iOS on a Windows machine.

Comment: Who said I am trying to build locally?  I am just trying to build the iOS version on my Windows machine using Sidekick with cloud build.